# Absolute positioning out of div

Tags: css

I have

```
<div id="content" style='position:relative; overflow:auto;'><img id="d"/></div>
```

`#d` is just some design element, which should be in that place on the picture below. Whatever I try, it does not show.

The CSS I've tried so far:

```
display:block;
position:absolute; 
margin-left:-10px; 
left:-10px; 
z-index:999;
```

[image: illustration]

Comment: Why is `#d` *within* `#content` in the HTML when you want it outside?

Comment: im not able to use another div to wrap these two

Comment: because content takes 100% of the body width

Comment: post it as a fiddle, it will be easy for us to help

Comment: If it takes up 100% of the body width, how are you ever going to see something that is positioned outside of it?

Comment: `#d is just some design element`. does it image or div ?

Comment: @oGeez body width in my interpetation does dot include margin, i have auto margins and fixed width. nevermind. Thought this was possible from inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element should be placed outside, if it's supposed to be outside - let's try to avoid negative margins, etc..

Try setting a `top` to your element as well - relative and absolute positioning has to have both vertical(top/bottom) and horizontal(left/right) setting.

Answer (score 1):

add top attribute

This is what I have tried and works you have to set left like the `-width` of your image

```
<div id="content" style='position:relative;  width:200px; margin:0 auto; background:black; height:100px;'><img id="d" src="http://placehold.it/50x50"/></div>


#d{
    position:absolute; 
    left:-50px;  //width of image
    top:0;
  }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5UAuU/)

Comment: What is the result that you have now? @RápliAndrás

Comment: why do you use `z-index:999;` ?

Comment: is in the example of OP don't know which use of that he wants but I can remove it isn't necessary @kevpoccs

Comment: Soory for my question I haven't see this line ^^

Answer (score 1):

If you want the absolute positioned element to be placed outside of the parent, then you can set the left as -ve value like `left:-35px;` and with similar +ve value of `margin-left` of parent container.

You can try this CSS

```
#content{ 
    position:relative;
    height:200px; 
    background:black;
    margin-left:35px
}

#d{
    display:block;
    position:absolute; 
    left:-35px; 
    z-index:999;
    background:red;
}
```

with markup

```
<div id="content">
  <img id="d" />
</div>
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2w5S6/)

Comment: That's nice, but I don't really wanna push away the whole `#content` div.

Comment: Thanks but if you don't want to push then where do you want to put that red element? as in your picture you can see the space beneath of that red element which put the margin from the left to the black content.

Comment: It should appear on the body margin (which is set to auto).

Comment: Then why don't you put that `#d` element outside of the `#content` div? what do you think? and set the `left:10px` or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Small code - fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/52YtG/

```
<div class="mainDIV">
    <div class="miniMe"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.mainDIV {
    position:relative;
    left:20px; { or to make a space for element - margin-left:20px; }
    top:20px;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background:blue;
}
.miniMe {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:-10px;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    background:red;
}
```